# Nhibernate inconsistent fetching behavior

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Here is my code

```
if (des.X == null)
{
    if (src.IsL)
    {
        des.X = new Y();
        var l = lRepo.Find().Where(file => file.Id == src.drId).First();
        ((Y)des.X).L = l;
    }
    else
    {

        D d = dRepo.Get(src.DrugId);
        if (d is N)
        {
            des.X = new Y();
            ((Y)des.X).D = d;
            ((Y)des.X).L = ((N)d).L;
        }
        else
        if (d is IF)
        {
            des.X = new IeI();
            des.X.D = d;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem happens when I ask `if (d is N)`

At the first time when I send a create request and I send a **N Id** , it evaluates it as true but when I send the same data for update it evaluates it as false.

I am a little confused and I have no logical explanation for that, so could anyone help me to resolve this issue.

When update it returns a proxy but when creating it returns a normal entity.

Untrack and not lazy load solutions work in this case but I do not think that they are efficient solutions.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably obtaining a proxy of a mapped base class. It derives from the base class, not from your concrete class, causing your type test to fail.

Without more details about your model, I can only propose a worst case solution. (It would be preferable to avoid being in a situation where you have to deal with testing the type of base class proxies against expected concrete types.)

In your base class, add this:

```
public virtual Type GetUnproxiedType()
{
    return GetType();
}
```

Change your test to:

```
if (typeof(NonInfantDrugRegistration).IsAssignableFrom(
    drugRegistration.GetUnproxiedType()))
```

This should work because a NHibernate proxy redirects calls to methods and properties, excepted the id and methods belonging to the object type (and some others). It redirects calls to a concrete unproxied instance it will dynamically create and load on first call to redirect. This concrete instance will not be a proxy and will have the expected type. So the `GetUnproxiedType` method above will be redirected to an unproxied `NonInfantDrugRegistration`, which will then return your concrete type.